# Why doesn't this question appear as "protected" anymore?

Tags: support, closed-questions, 10k-tools, protected-questions

After poking around a bit in the 10K tools to see how much things have...changed, I noticed [this particular post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72106/1079354).

There aren't any qualms about its quality, but what I *do* have a qualm with is that unprotect link in it.  I can [see in the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72106/timeline) (17 September 2011 for those who won't search for "protected") that it's been protected before, and I don't see an unprotect event in there.

Why is the protection masked because it's closed?  Shouldn't the protection be *removed* realistically if it's closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although closing a question is, effectively, protecting it from being answered by *anyone* (this is why the protection notice is masked, because it's redundant), protection and closure are two separate concepts; one does not affect the other.

Think of protection and closure as two distinct *layers* of restriction, with protection being the inner, somewhat restrictive layer and closure being the completely impenetrable outer layer. You can see that the question was reopened once after it was protected and before its current closed state. When the question is reopened, the protected status needs to remain so that it will continue to be protected from drive-by answers.

It's similar to locking a question that is already closed: a question can be locked whether it's open or closed, but when it's unlocked it needs to stay closed if that was how it was at the time of being locked. The difference between this and closing a protected question is that, because a question can be locked for any reason unrelated to closure, the closure notice isn't masked because it's not necessarily redundant.

Comment: That's fair. Thanks for clearing it up.